# Get Service after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-service

I have a `Service` and when there is a screen rotation, It is bound again but `onServiceConnected` on `ServiceConnection()` is not called so my deviceController is null.

Is there any way to get the bound service ?

Here the code :

```
private MyService myService;
private ServiceConnection myServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection()
{
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
    {
        MyActivity.this.myService = ((MyService.LocalBinder) service).getService();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
    {
        MyActivity.this.myService = null;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // code to bind service
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that the `unBindService` is not called when orientation change.

It would be good to bind service in `onStart()` and unbind in `onStop()`. So that when the `Activity` is not visible , You don't really requited the service connection.

This will make sure the service is unbind when not required.

Check this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: No. `onStart` is called when activity is visible to user , followed by `onResume` where user can interact with Activity.